# inline conditional check to apply extension to variable?

Tags: c#

If specific condition is true, then I want the variable to be converted, but if it's false then leave it as is. The whole idea is to achieve that in the line below, without adding extra lines before it.

```
bool my_condition = ....;
string xyz = MyClass1.MySubclass2.VeryLongVariableName.(my_condition ? .ToShortTimeString()  : ());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [C# conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator). It's usually called [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) in other languages.

```
bool my_condition = ....;
string xyz = my_condition ? something_variable.ToShortTimeString() : something_variable;
```

Comment: I know that, the reason i asked is that something_variable is actually too long in my case:  `currentItem.GetType().GetProperty(field_name).GetValue(currentItem, null)`

Comment: @T.Todua I don't understand your problem. Can you elaborate further? What do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

```
string xyz=my_condition.any()?something_variable.ToShortTimeString():"somethingelse";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Reflection

```
bool my_condition = ....;
var xyz = something_variable.GetType()
    .GetMethod(my_condition ? "ToShortTimeString" : "ToLongTimeString")
    .Invoke(something_variable, null);
```

You might need to specify `BindingFlags` depending on the methods used.

Comment: problem is that i dont want ToLongTImeString. I just want to leave as is in all other cases. actually, i didnt want to mention "something_variable" twice, because it is too long in my case: `currentItem.GetType().GetProperty(field_name).GetValue(currentItem, null)` . that's why i wante inline solution with a tricky concern.

Comment: @T.Todua try `ToString` instead of `ToLongTimeString`, although it might lead to ambiguous match found.